# pyqt5 tabifyDockWidget and hide the tabbar

Tags: pyqt5, qdockwidget, qtabbar

Im creating a pyqt5 app that uses dockable widgets. The initial design used a stacked widget with nice buttons to switch pages.  Ive been able to mimic the behavior by using tabifyDockWidget to place the pages in a dockable setting. I use the raise_() function to raise the dockedwidgets on my button presses.

Everything works great..  except: i cant get rid of/hide that ugly tab bar.  I can find the tab bar using mainwindow findchildren().  I can seemingly hide() it (no errors), but it just doesnt go away. it stares at me. laughs at me.

I started writing code to catch location change events and then display/hide page widgets (without the tabifyDockWidget being called), but its crazy complicated for what i need:

Are there any ways to create tabifiedDockWidgets without having the tab bar visible? Or, is there a way to hide the tab bar once created with the tabifyDockWidgets?
thanks!!

Comment: No, there are no easy nor reliable ways, as what you're trying to do with dock widgets is not the way they're were intended to be used. Besides, the feature is called "tabified" specifically because of the ***tab*** part.